# Interrupting and restarting a python script

Tags: python, restart, keyboardinterrupt

Let's say that I have a script that looks like this

```
myInput = input(int('Enter a number: '))
while myInput > 0:
    print(myInput)
    myInput-=1
```

Is there a way that I can interrupt the while loop and return to the part that asks for user input?

Comment: Yes, you should handle [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) exception.

Comment: Or you can simply put an input() in your while loop if you want you user to give you several input.

Comment: Why do you want to interrupt the while loop?

Comment: Did you mean to put ‘while True:’ at the top of your code?

Comment: `input(int(` should be `int(input(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to a `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
def foo():
    try:
        myInput = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        while myInput > 0:
            print(myInput)
            myInput-=1
        return True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return False

while not foo():
    pass
```

Comment: oops fixed that